# How to change a style of an HTML element in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have two React components

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="appWrapper">
        <ConfigureWindow />
        <button id="configureClocksButton">Configure clocks</button>
        <section id="clocksHere"></section>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```
const ConfigureWindow = () => (
  <div id="configureWindowWrapper">
    <div id="configureWindow">
      <section id="addCitySection">TODO: adding a city</section>
      <div id="verticalLine"></div>
      <section id="listOfCities">
        <header>
          <h1>Available cities</h1>
          <div id="closeConfigureWindowWrapper">
            <img src="..\src\images\exit.png" id="closeConfigureWindow" alt="" />
          </div>
        </header>
        <section id="availableCities"></section>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

I want "ConfigureWindow" to be shown when "configureClocksButton". I tried to execute it with props, state and a function but got errors. It also would be nice if you explain me how to create new React components with React functions?

Comment: It's a bit difficult to understand your post, but I gather you want to click the button with `id="configureClocksButton"` and do something with the `ConfigureWindow` component?

Comment: Yes. id="configureClocksButton" is a button and a user clicks on to show ConfigureWindow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use the React.JS event onClick (https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html), and a state to store the action. To create a function component, you just have to return the JSX you want to render, and use hooks (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) and then do a conditional rendering (https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html):

```
const App = () => {
    const [toggleConfiguration, setToggleConfiguration] = useState(false)

    return (
      <div id="appWrapper">
        {toggleConfiguration && <ConfigureWindow />}
        <button onClick{() => setToggleConfiguration(true)} id="configureClocksButton">Configure clocks</button>
        <section id="clocksHere"></section>
      </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: What to change at ConfigureWindow so it works?

Comment: You don't need to change the ConfigureWindow component.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit difficult to understand your post, but I gather you want to click the button with `id="configureClocksButton"` and conditionally render the `ConfigureWindow` component.

You can accomplish this with some boolean state, a click handler to toggle the state, and some conditional rendering.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  this.state = {
    showConfigureWindow: false,
  }

  toggleShowConfigureWindow = () => this.setState(prevState => ({
    showConfigureWindow: !prevState.showConfigureWindow,
  }))

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="appWrapper">
        {showConfigureWindow && <ConfigureWindow />}
        <button
          id="configureClocksButton"
          onClick={this.toggleShowConfigureWindow}
        >
          Configure clocks
        </button>
        <section id="clocksHere"></section>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

A function component equivalent:

```
const App = () => {
  const [showConfigureWindow, setShowConfigureWindow] = React.useState(false);

  const toggleShowConfigureWindow = () => setShowConfigureWindow(show => !show);
  
  return (
    <div id="appWrapper">
      {showConfigureWindow && <ConfigureWindow />}
      <button
        id="configureClocksButton"
        onClick={toggleShowConfigureWindow}
      >
        Configure clocks
      </button>
      <section id="clocksHere"></section>
    </div>
  );
}
```